# Angular 15 - Consider using the @Inject decorator to specify an injection token

Tags: angular, typescript

After using angular's factory provider and sending two arguments in factory.service.ts, I wanted to display 'factory' and a boolean value.

It seems to work fine in other angular versions, but a problem occurs in angular 15 version.

I don't know which part is the problem....

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FactoryService } from '../factory.service';
import { LogService } from '../log.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  providers: [LogService, 
   {provide: 'another', useClass: LogService}, 
   {provide: 'same',useExisting: LogService}, 
   {provide: 'githubUrl',useValue: 'https://github.com/abcd'}, 
   {provide: 'factory',useFactory: (logService) => {
              return new FactoryService(logService, true);},
              deps: [FactoryService]
   }]
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{

    constructor(private log:LogService, 
        @Inject('another') private another, 
        @Inject('same') private same,
        @Inject('githubUrl') private url,
        @Inject('factory') private factory         
        ) {
        console.log("this.log === this.another", this.log === this.another)
        console.log("this.log === this.same", this.log === this.same)
        console.log(this.url)
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.log.info('logservice');
        this.factory.log();
    }

}
```

factory.service.ts

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { LogService } from "./log.service";

@Injectable()
export class FactoryService {
    constructor(private logService: LogService, private isFactory: boolean) {}

    public log() {
        this.logService.info(`factory ${this.isFactory}`);
    }
}
```

Error

```
Error: src/app/factory.service.ts:6:57 - error NG2003: No suitable injection token for parameter 'isFactory' of class 'FactoryService'.
  Consider using the @Inject decorator to specify an injection token.

6     constructor(private logService: LogService, private isFactory: boolean) {}
                                                          ~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/factory.service.ts:6:68
    6     constructor(private logService: LogService, private isFactory: boolean) {}
                                                                         ~~~~~~~
    This type is not supported as injection token.
```

I've looked at the official documentation, but I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

As per the error message suggested, you should use `@Inject` decorator for your custom parameter, else Angular will treat it as a dependency and try to resolve it.

Since you don't have such `isFactory` provider, Angular throwed error.

Add @Inject decorator with named `isFactory`

### factory.service.ts

```ts
......
    constructor(private logService: LogService, @Inject('isFactory') private isFactory: boolean) {}
......
```

Provide the `isFactory` value and remove second param in `new FactoryService`

### home.component.ts

```ts
......
  providers: [LogService, 
   {provide: 'another', useClass: LogService}, 
   {provide: 'same',useExisting: LogService}, 
   {provide: 'githubUrl',useValue: 'https://github.com/abcd'}, 
   {
      provide: 'isFactory',
      useValue: true,
   },
   {provide: 'factory',useFactory: (logService) => {
              return new FactoryService(logService);},
              deps: [FactoryService]
   },
]
})
```

The code is not tested.

Refer to https://www.positronx.io/how-to-pass-parameters-to-angular-service-using-inject/ for more info.

Comment: thanks, I tried it and error in terminal was gone but in console of browser(after npm start) there are errors, its so weired..

1. ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[FactoryService -> FactoryService -> FactoryService]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for FactoryService!

2. NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[FactoryService -> FactoryService -> FactoryService]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for FactoryService!

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to resolve is to use Injection tokens. If you use `factory` then these are tree-shakeable.

```
const IS_FACTORY = new InjectionToken<boolean>('Is factory', {
  providedIn: 'root', // optional
  factory: () => true
});
```

To provide,

```
providers: [{ provide: IS_FACTORY, useValue: false}],
```

And if you want to use in your component with type safety

```
const isFactory = inject(IS_FACTORY); // or the @Inject method
```

Second argument of `inject` allows the usual resolution modifiers of optional, self, host etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't know where else to put the code to make it work. What part of my code should the code you show replace and what file should it go into? I tried putting it in every line but still getting the error.